# Can I update a property in the redux store without triggering a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to keep some data in the redux store that does not affect React components at all. However, each time I update the data, React re-renders the app. Is there a way to not trigger the re-render?

Comment: If the data does not affect React components then why do you keep it in the store?

Comment: @devserkan where should I keep the global app datas instead?

Comment: I don't know what kind of data is this but can't you keep it somewhere else as exported then import it where you need?

Comment: @devserkan the data is dynamic, I thought redux is used to store global data? I think I'm mistaken..

Comment: I don't know the use case but if you give more detail then more experienced people make good suggestions. But, Redux keeps the global state of the app. So, the data it keeps is related to the app. If you won't reach this data via Redux again why do you want to keep it there?

Comment: @devserkan I think the problem is solved, I just have to not have components listen to that piece of data in the store as Chaim Friedman pointed out in the answer, thank you anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating data in redux will only trigger a re-render to a component if the data that specific component is "subscribing" to has changed.

For example, consider the following `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cars: state.cars,
  }
}
```

The component which defined this `mapStateToProps` will only render if the `cars` array is not the same as it was the last time the function ran. Now, if you have a piece of data in the store which is not defined in any `mapStateToProps`, no component will render as as result of changing that data point.

[Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connect) is the documentation for `connect` and `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: I think this is the solution. Thank you. Right now I subscribe to the whole render, so any change will cause the entire app to re-render.